# One-dimensional Sheaves and Pushforwards of Vector Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Throughout, I want my ambient space $X$ to be a smooth projective variety of dimension at least two.

I believe we can at least say the following.  If $\mathcal{E}$ is a pure one-dimensional coherent sheaf on $X$, and the support of $\mathcal{E}$ is a smooth projective curve $C \subset X$, then $\mathcal{E}$ is the pushforward of a vector bundle on $C$.  I believe this is true because pure sheaves are torsion-free restricted to their support, and torsion-free sheaves on a smooth projective curve are locally-free.

Now, removing the assumption that the support be smooth, I am wondering to what extent (if any) pure one-dimensional coherent sheaves on smooth projective varieties are pushforwards of vector bundles.  Given a pure one-dimensional sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ supported on $C$, if we compose the normalization with the inclusion

$$\widetilde{C} \rightarrow C \hookrightarrow X,$$

can we always realize $\mathcal{E}$ as the pushforward of a locally-free sheaf on $\widetilde{C}$ to $X$?  What if $\mathcal{E}$ has scheme-theoretic support on a non-reduced curve $C$?

Answer (score 1):

The pushforward of a sheaf is always scheme-theoretically supported on the corresponding subscheme. So, if the scheme-theoretical support of a sheaf is not reduced, it is not the pushforward from the corresponding reduced subscheme.